# Element arrays and nested elements in Gazebo 1.x

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am porting the gazebo_ros_actuator_array plug-in (in the actuator_array stack) to Gazebo 1.x. Unfortunately, according to http://gazebosim.org/wiki/sdf_plugin, plug-ins specified in an SDF file can only have key-value pairs as their parameters. The actuator array plug-in has parameters like these:

```
<joint>
    <name>camera_servo_joint</name>
    <home>0</home>
    <p>10</p>
    <i>0</i>
    <d>0</d>
    <iClamp>0</iClamp>
  </joint>
  <joint>
    <name>camera_axle_joint</name>
    <home>0</home>
    <p>10</p>
    <i>0</i>
    <d>0</d>
    <iClamp>0</iClamp>
  </joint>
  <joint>
    <name>right_axle_joint</name>
    <controlType>velocityEffort</controlType>
  </joint>
```

Are there plans to support multiple elements with the same name (e.g. "joint") and nested elements? Currently, my work-around is to add a jointFileName parameter to the plug-in, use the parameter to specify a YAML file, and store the joint information in the file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38314/element-arrays-and-nested-elements-in-gazebo-1.x/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-07-16**:
who is the intended audience for the XML you posted above?  Is it a gazebo plugin you've written?

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on 2012-07-19**:
The XML contains parameters for the gazebo_ros_actuator_array plug-in (http://www.ros.org/wiki/actuator_array_gazebo_plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From Nate Koenig on the Gazebo mailing list:

`This is now fixed in the dev branch of gazebo. There is also a simple example in <gazebo_sources>/examples/plugins/parameters`

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2012-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0